Reorder columns in a SAS dataset
I have the following dataset:



ID
X1
X2
Xn
Y1
Y2
Yn




IC 01
2
4
5
5
9
8


IC 02
1
5
8
3
4
7



And i would like to have the following:



ID
X1
Y1
X2
Y2
Xn
Yn




IC 01
2
5
4
9
5
8


IC 02
1
3
5
4
8
7



I used the transpose function in SAS EG but I could not find the right way to order my columns in the following order
-> X1 - Y1 - X2 - Y2 - X3 - Y3 - ... - Xn - Yn
Any recommendations are welcome
Thanks!

Transpose will convert your WIDE dataset into a TALL dataset.  But you want another WIDE dataset.  So you would need to TRANSPOSE the data twice.  With a step inbetween to reorder the rows so that the resulting variables are defined in a different order.

Just define the variables in the order you want.
 data want;
    length ID $8 X1 Y1 X2 Y2 ..... Xn Yn 8;
    set have;
 run;

Or perhaps you can take advantage of the fact that using a RETAIN statement will force SAS to set the position of the variable, but not the type.
 data want;
    retain ID X1 Y1 X2 Y2 ..... Xn Yn ;
    set have;
 run;

If you are too lazy to type all of the variable names then just generate them.  Perhaps with a data step:
data _null_;
   do i=1 to 20;
     put 'X' i 'Y' i @ ;
   end;
run;

Then just copy the list from the log and paste it back into your program.
Or you could use macro code to generate the list:
 %macro names(n);
   %local i;
   %do i=1 %to &n; X&i Y&i %end;
 %mend names;
 data want;
    retain ID %names(10) ;
    set have;
 run;
 


It worked! Thanks a lot!
